# Sending Data from Angular Front End to NodeJS in a json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am currently trying to connect an AngularJS front end to a NodeJS back end application. The ideal goal is to read, write, edit and delete data off a **json file**, not a database. 
I have tried setting up the post method on both sides but it says that my **json** file containing the information is `404`.

I have never before implemented a back end after the front end was created, so I am quite unsure how to proceed with this.

**This is my Angular Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

app.controller('dashCtrl', function($scope, $http){

   $http.get('/Alpha/json/details.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.details = response.data;
        console.log(details);
    });

   $scope.newDetails = {};

    $scope.selectItem = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        $scope.clickedDetails = item;
    };

    $scope.updateItem = function(){

    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(){
        $scope.details.splice($scope.details.indexOf($scope.clickedDetails), 1);
    };

   $scope.saveItem = function(){        
        $scope.details.push({ 'id':$scope.id, 'system': $scope.system, 'date':$scope.date, 'priority':$scope.priority, 'description':$scope.description, 'status':$scope.status });
        // Writing it to the server
        //      
        var item = {
            id:$scope.id, 
            system: $scope.system, 
            date:$scope.date, 
            priority:$scope.priority, 
            description:$scope.description, 
            status:$scope.status
        };  

        $http.post('../json/details.json', item).then(function(item, status) {
            console.log('Data posted successfully');
        });

        // Making the fields empty
        //
        $scope.id = ''; 
        $scope.system = '';
        $scope.date = '';
        $scope.priority = '';
        $scope.description = '';
        $scope.status = ''; 
    };

});
```

**The NodeJS I am running at the back:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.post('/Alpha/pages/json/details.json', function(req, res) {
    console.log(details);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My HTML form:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">

    <thead style="background-color:#002244; color:#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th> Issue </th>
            <th> System </th>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th > Priority </th>
            <th > Description </th>
            <th > Status </th>
            <th style="background:white;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Add +" style=" border-color:#FFBE00; color: black;background-color:#FFBE00;">Add</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat=" item in details ">
            <td > {{item.id}}</td>
            <td > {{item.system}} </td>
            <td > {{item.date}}</td>
            <td class="{{item.priority}}-priority"> {{item.priority}} </td>
            <td > {{item.description}}</td>
            <td > {{item.status}} </td>
            <td>
                <a href ="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete" ng-click="selectItem(item)">Delete</a>
                <a href ="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" ng-click="selectItem(item)">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Why am I receiving a **404** on my json file when I am trying to post to it? How can I specify from the post method in NodeJS to use the one in Angular?

Comment: I think you need to give the complete path instead of `../json/details.json`

Comment: In your `Network` tab of your `Dev Tools` right click on the `details.json` call (for which you are receiving the `404` error) and click on `Open in new tab`, and ensure that the path displayed in the address bar is a valid one.

Comment: @DavidR I can access the json file just fine, yet it keeps giving me a 404

Comment: you are using `$http.get(..)` whereas at your backend you are expecting a post requests as `app.post(...)` either make both of them get request or post requests

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you put the filename and extension in your API .... trey to give End-Point URL... so for example:

in Angular cllas:

```
 $http.post('../Alpha/pages/json/', item).then(function(item, status) {
            console.log('Data posted successfully');
        });
```

In your Node.js

```
   app.post('/Alpha/pages/json/', function(req, res) {
        console.log(details);
        res.end();
    });
```

Comment: sadly that did not fix the issue that I am having.

Comment: sorry but the json is in a file? or is generated programmatically from your back end?

Comment: the json is in a static file that I am using.

Comment: ahhh ok ... so is it store on the back end? .. or aalso in a front end directory? ..

Comment: it's to be store in the front end. the only "back end" script that I am using is just this small nodejs script. I've written it only to add, delete, edit data that is being displayed on the front end. I cannot use a DB for this but a static file.

Comment: so if you want you can retrive it from FRont end like  $http.get('.RELATIVEPATH_TO_DIRECTORY/filename.json', item).then(function(item, status) {
            console.log('Data posted successfully');
        });    or by back end in Node.js var config = require('./test.json');  app.post('/Alpha/pages/json/', function(req, res) {
        console.log(details);
        res.json(config);
    });

Comment: I want to be able to post data in the file, which is achievable only if I have a server running with a script at the back end.